# Having issues with jQuery DOM selection of class elements

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following html:

```
<li class="active active-tab">
    <span class="text">Tab 1</span>
</li>
<li class="next next-tab">
    <span class="text">Tab 2</span>
</li>
```

And the following jquery:

```
$('.next-tab').click(function() {
    $('.active-tab').addClass( 'prev prev-tab' );
    $('.active-tab').removeClass('active active-tab');
    $('.next-tab').addClass('active active-tab');
    $('.next-tab').removeClass('next next-tab');
});

$('.prev-tab').click(function() {
    $('.active-tab').addClass( 'next next-tab' );
    $('.active-tab').removeClass('next active-tab');
    $('.prev-tab').addClass( 'active active-tab' );
    $('.prev-tab').removeClass('prev prev-tab');
});
```

When I click on `.next-tab` `li` element, it does change the first `li` element to have classes `prev prev-tab`.

But when I click on the first `li` element, that now has `prev prev-tab` as classes, it doesn't execute the jQuery, even though it is stated in the script.

Why isn't the `$('.prev-tab').click(function()` executing when pressing on the li element, that has `prev prev-tab`?

For easy error diagnostics I have created this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afqsz861/1/) (webconsole needed :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly know what you wish to achieve here. But to answer your question, I think *binding the event higher up in the DOM tree (like **document**)* should do the trick, so:

```
$(document).on('click', '.next-tab', function(){
    $('.active-tab').addClass( 'prev prev-tab' );
    $('.active-tab').removeClass('active active-tab');
    $('.next-tab').addClass('active active-tab');
    $('.next-tab').removeClass('next next-tab');
});
$(document).on('click', '.prev-tab', function(){
    $('.active-tab').addClass( 'next next-tab' );
    $('.active-tab').removeClass('next active-tab');
    $('.prev-tab').addClass( 'active active-tab' );
    $('.prev-tab').removeClass('prev prev-tab');
});
```

would work in your case.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.next-tab', function(){
    $('.active-tab').addClass( 'prev prev-tab' );
    $('.active-tab').removeClass('active active-tab');
    $('.next-tab').addClass('active active-tab');
    $('.next-tab').removeClass('next next-tab');
});
$(document).on('click', '.prev-tab', function(){
  $('.active-tab').addClass( 'next next-tab' );
    $('.active-tab').removeClass('next active-tab');
    $('.prev-tab').addClass( 'active active-tab' );
    $('.prev-tab').removeClass('prev prev-tab');
});
```

```css
li {
  width:150px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#EDCFA5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="active active-tab">
        <span class="text">Tab 1</span>
    </li>
    <li class="next next-tab">
        <span class="text">Tab 2</span>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because at the time of `document` load, there was no element available with `prev-tab` class. To get around this, you need to place these elements in a wrapper and use the [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event on the wrapper like below-

```
$('.next-tab').click(function() {
    $('.active-tab').addClass( 'prev prev-tab' );
    $('.active-tab').removeClass('active active-tab');
    $('.next-tab').addClass('active active-tab');
    $('.next-tab').removeClass('next next-tab');
});

$('body').on('click', '.prev-tab', function() {
    $('.active-tab').addClass( 'next next-tab' );
    $('.active-tab').removeClass('active active-tab');
    $('.prev-tab').addClass( 'active active-tab' );
    $('.prev-tab').removeClass('prev prev-tab');
});
```

Notice that I have used `body` here, but you can use any other element, provided that it is the parent of the DOM element for which you need to trigger this event.

Updated JS Fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/afqsz861/3/

Comment: Ty for the answer - upvoted because is does work in the case. Another answer worked better in my case! But again ty for the help! :)